# Should "romaji" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, loanwords

Should, "romaji", a loanword from Japanese, be capitalized because it is ultimately related to "Rome", which is a proper noun?

I came across [Should capitalization be preserved in loanwords?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15241/should-capitalization-be-preserved-in-loanwords) , but "romaji" is usually not written in romaji in Japanese. For example, it's written [ローマ字](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E5%AD%97) in the Japanese edition of Wikipedia. How heterological!

Comment: Can you please change the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Romaji" in Japanese is not derived from Rome, the city (per se).

It IS derived from "romanization," that is the use of the "roman" alphabet to describe Japanese sounds. But "romanization" is in the lower case, and therefore, so should "romaji."

Comment: Even *roman* referring to roman type, is not capitalized.  And certainaly *romanji* is further from Rome than that!

Comment: @GEdgar: It's "romaji". :)

Comment: @GEdgar That is a quite special case.  Roman is normally capitalised.  According to wikipedia: "The name "roman" is customarily applied uncapitalized distinguishing early Italian typefaces of the Renaissance period and most subsequent seriffed types based on them, from Roman letters dating from classical antiquity."

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Please don't invent etymology.  It's derived from *Rōma* ("Rome") + *ji* ("character").  It's not derived from the English words *Roman* or *romanization*.

Answer (score 5):

In English the convention is to capitalise proper nouns.  If *romaji* were a proper noun I would certainly capitalise it, however, in this case it is only related to a proper noun.  Here there is a grey area where some words are inconsistently capitalised, for example, *anglophone*.  It seems in this particular case convention is not to capitalise, as seen with the similar word *kanji*.

Answer (score 2):

The word *romaji* is a noun, and **it is not directly derived** from a proper noun. So, it is not typically capitalized (as attested, for example, in the *Oxford English Dictionary*). It is different from, e.g., the adjective *Roman* (related to the modern city of Rome, or to the ancient Rome).

Answer (score 2):

[Kanjidict](http://kanjidict.stc.cx/japkanji.php?d1=on&s=%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E5%AD%97&max=10&exact=on&btnJ=Search%20JA%E2%86%92EN&d3=on&d9=on&d15=on) gives the translation as lowercase *romaji*:

[image]

For the benefit of those who don't know what this word means, it is a foreign word rendered in Japanese using Roman letters.

Comment: Does it have to be a foreign word?

Comment: @Henry: No. As you can see above, it can be a transliteration of a Japanese word.