# Should I write "repartee" with an accent?

Tags: meaning, nouns, orthography, diacritics

Does *repartee* need an accent with it in writing? Also, what does it mean?

**Edit:** Can you please provide an example sentence or two? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diacriticals and non-English letters in anglicized loan words: keep 'em, dump 'em, italicize the words, or what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/diacriticals-and-non-english-letters-in-anglicized-loan-words-keep-em-dump-em)

Comment: @Robusto In this case, the original French word apparently doesn't have an accent either. I don't know French, so I can't be sure.

Comment: so why is sautee spelled with accent and repartee not? :( ahhh i''ll never remember all this for my vocab test

Comment: @katie: seriously, no offense and no harm meant, I don't want to hurt anybody's feelings or step on any toes, **but**. I would be more worried about memorizing the correct spelling of more common words, such as "you", "I", and "please".

Comment: @RegDwight :*( I said I would spell better in the other question, don't worry. I'm trying!

Comment: No, you shouldn't!

Answer (score 2):

*Repartee* is “conversation marked by a series of witty retorts” ([wiktionary](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/repartee)).

The word is spelled with no accents. It is apparently from the French *repartie* (with no accent).

Comment: can u use it in a sentence plz? :) thx!

Comment: @katie [Google dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary?q=repartee&langpair=en|en) offers several examples.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/), the definition of *[repartee](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1284279#m_en_us1284279)* is

> conversation or speech characterized by quick, witty comments or replies.

*Repartee* is always spelled without an accent. It is pronounced *re-par-TEE* (also, less commonly, *re-par-TAY* in the US).

Example:

> That was the best outing we've had in years! Our hosts were fabulous, the dinner was fantastic, and the ensuing *repartee* was invigorating.