# Usage of "À la carte" on menus in English

Tags: expression-choice

On a menu which contains both "family style" dishes and individual items (serves 1 person) would it be correct to name the individual items section "À la carte"?

Comment: Appetizers, Entrees, Sides, ... maybe look at other menus for inspiration. Some "We only do family sized meals" restaurants might simply say "Petite" or "Indvidual" serving.

Comment: ["Honestly, I feel affected writing à la carte when every damn diner you walk into has an "a la carte" (or "ala carte" or "a la cart") category on the menu."](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/13343/2303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make sense. 'A la carte' is usually used to describe modular menu items that can be mixed and matched, as opposed to a 'table d'hote' or fixed menu. In your context I think 'a la carte' is fine, but you might want to clarify what is meant by it.

Comment: do you see a different way to mention the individual items? I thought of personal dishes but it sounds too trivial.